# PixiJS: Load custom font

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, pixi.js

i am currently learning Pixijs.
I went through the tutorial of this guy: [github.com/kittykatattack/learningPixi](https://github.com/kittykatattack/learningPixi)
Nice one btw.

Environement:
Xampp, Firefox, Pixijs, HTML, CSS

Now I try to load a custom font.
The first time I load the Page where my Pixijs project should run, the fonts are not showing up and the console shows some error messages...
The second time I load the page (without deleting the cache) the text is showing up with the given font!

Why?!

Here are the snippets for loading the font:

**index.html:**

```
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' />
    <style>
        @font-face{
            font-family: "FFFForward";
            src: url("assets/fonts/fffforward.TTF");
        }

        * {padding: 0; margin: 0}
    </style>
```

**app.js:**

```
function DrawText(){

PointsTopText = new Text(
    "P1: " + PointsTop,
    {fontFamily: 'FFFForward, Arial', fontSize: 32, fill: 'white'}
);
PointsBotText = new Text(
    "Cpu: " + PointsBot,
    {fontFamily: 'FFFForward, Arial', fontSize: 32, fill: 'white'}
);

PointsTopText.position.set(0, Renderer.height / 2 - 32 * 2);
PointsBotText.position.set(0, Renderer.height / 2);

World.addChild(PointsTopText);
World.addChild(PointsBotText);
}
```

Here is the error log of the console:

**console:**

```
downloadable font: bad search range (font-family: "FFFForward" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:0) source: [path]/assets/fonts/fffforward.TTF  PixiJs:6:14
downloadable font: bad range shift (font-family: "FFFForward" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:0) source: [path]/assets/fonts/fffforward.TTF  PixiJs:6:14
downloadable font: cmap: bad id_range_offset (font-family: "FFFForward" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:0) source: [path]/assets/fonts/fffforward.TTF  PixiJs:6:14
downloadable font: hdmx: the table should not be present when bit 2 and 4 of the head->flags are not set (font-family: "FFFForward" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:0) source: [path]/assets/fonts/fffforward.TTF  PixiJs:6:14
downloadable font: hdmx: Table discarded (font-family: "FFFForward" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:0) source: [path]/assets/fonts/fffforward.TTF  PixiJs:6:14
```

As i said, this message appears only the very first time i load my page.
The second time everything is fine.

What can i do to prevent this?

Why does this happen?

What is the meaning of this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use webfontloader - https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader - to synchronously load your fonts *before* you do any drawing in PixiJS. This also works with other canvas-based apps.

**Put the following in the <head> section of your HTML page:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.6.26/webfont.js"></script>
<script>
    WebFont.load({
        google: {
            families: ['Press Start 2P']
        },
        active:e=>{
            console.log("font loaded!");
            // now start setting up your PixiJS (or canvas) stuff!
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I haven't been here for a while. I didn't tested your solution, but it makes sense to me.
I will test it later and give you my conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use PIXI.loader

```
const loader = new PIXI.loaders.Loader();
loader.add('fffforward', 'assets/fonts/fffforward.TTF');

loader.load((loader, resources) => {
    PointsTopText = new Text(
        "P1: " + PointsTop,
        {fontFamily: 'FFFForward', fontSize: 32, fill: 'white'}
    );
    World.addChild(PointsTopText);
});
```

Comment: Tried this solution as it looked more clean to me but seems not to work.

Also tried to import the font with the usual Angular method with my css but I guess that pixijs is not able to access the default fonts loaded in window?

Comment: PIXI.Loader doesn't currently work with fonts.  Use a 3rd party font loading solution as suggested by tonethar.

Comment: Now [PixiJS v7 works](https://www.pixijselementals.com/#fonts) with fonts out of the box!